# web scraping different number of variables (rvest)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) version 0.99.879 and use for the following task the package [rvest](/questions/tagged/rvest) version 0.3.2 (I am a beginner in web scraping techniques):

For a research project, I want to scrape websites of journals to extract information on the author(s), institutional affiliation(s) etc. of the specific article.  
 I do this in the following way:

```
#Specifying the url for desired website to be scraped (article)
webpage001 <- read_html("https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12286-017-0325-1")
#Using CSS selectors to scrape the rankings section (with Abstract)
abstract_html001 <- html_node(webpage001,".Para")
authors_html001 <- html_nodes(webpage001,".authors__name")
affiliation_html001 <- html_nodes(webpage001, ".affiliation__item")

#Converting the title data to text 
abstract001 <- html_text(abstract_html001)
authors001 <- html_text(authors_html001)
affiliation001 <- html_text(affiliation_html001)
# creating a data frame
text01 <- data.frame(Abstract = abstract001, Author = authors001, 
Institution = affiliation001)
text01
```

This works fine and I get one obs. and three variables. But there are also academic texts such as book reviews that do not contain an abstract. If I try the same for a review,

```
webpage002 <- read_html("https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12286-017-0324-2")
authors_html002 <- html_nodes(webpage002,".authors__name")
affiliation_html002 <- html_nodes(webpage002, ".affiliation__item")
authors002 <- html_text(authors_html002)
affiliation002 <- html_text(affiliation_html002)
# creating a data frame
text02 <- data.frame(Author = authors001, Institution = affiliation001)
text02
```

I get one obs. and two variables. At the end, I want to merge both data frames, but due to the unequal number of columns, the [rbind](/questions/tagged/rbind) function doesn't work. 
 For just a few texts, I could assign the following

```
abstract002 <- NA
text02 <- data.frame(Abstract = abstract002, Author = authors002, 
Institution = affiliation002)
text02

total <- rbind(text01, text02)
```

However, for a large amount of texts, this would be too much and I was wondering whether there is a way to do this differently or even semi-automatized (for instance, each time, a text has no abstract, an *NA* is assigned into the correct column).

Has anyone an idea how to do this or solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rvest` and `purrr`, we can do:

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url <- 'https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12286-017-0325-1'
url2 <- 'https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12286-017-0324-2'

l <- list(url, url2)

l %>% 
    map_df( ~{

        h <- read_html(.x)

        abstract <- html_node(h, '.Para') %>%
            html_text()

        author <- html_node(h, '.authors__name') %>% 
            html_text()

        affiliation <- html_node(h, '.affiliation__item') %>% 
            html_text()

        data.frame(abstract, author, affiliation, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    })
#>  abstract
#> 1 When the Cold War ended, many non-democratic...
#> 2 <NA>
#>               author
#> 1       MarleneÂ Mauk
#> 2 ChristinaÂ Forsbach
#>                                                                        affiliation
#> 1 Institut fÃ¼r PolitikwissenschaftJohannes Gutenberg-UniversitÃ¤t MainzMainzGermany
#> 2     Institut fÃ¼r SozialwissenschaftenUniversitÃ¤t HildesheimHildesheimDeutschland
```

Comment: Great it works. Thanks a lot (my former comment might have seen a mistake in the code, but it wasn't in there - the CSSselector was wrong on the website for another text.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's fake data:

```
df1 <- data.frame( Abstract = letters[1:3], Author = letters[4:6], Institution = letters[7:9] )
df2 <- data.frame( Author = letters[10:12], Institution = letters[13:15] )

df1
  Abstract Author Institution
1        a      d           g
2        b      e           h
3        c      f           i

df2
  Author Institution
1      j           m
2      k           n
3      l           o
```

I suggest adding a column `Obs` to keep a unique identifier for each observation:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate( Obs = 1:nrow(df1) )
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate( Obs = (nrow(df1)+1):(nrow(df1)+nrow(df2)) )

  Abstract Author Institution Obs
1        a      d           g   1
2        b      e           h   2
3        c      f           i   3
```

Then `gather` the data first into a long format and merge them (only showing `head`):

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
       gather(key,value,-Obs) %>% 
       rbind(gather(df2,key,value,-Obs))

   Obs         key value
1    1    Abstract     a
2    2    Abstract     b
3    3    Abstract     c
4    1      Author     d
5    2      Author     e
```

Then `spread` the data again:

```
df3 <- df3 %>% spread(key=key,value=value)

  Obs Abstract Author Institution
1   1        a      d           g
2   2        b      e           h
3   3        c      f           i
4   4     <NA>      j           m
5   5     <NA>      k           n
6   6     <NA>      l           o
```